# How can I make a slide animation in my countdown in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, expo, countdown

I'm wondering how I could make my countdown have a slide down animation for each digit that changes but I am unable to figure out how I'd be able to do so.

So far I've only managed to get the base functionality of the countdown working:

```
export default class Countdown extends React.Component {
state={
    eventDate:moment.duration().add({hours:1,minutes:15,seconds:0}),
    hours:0,
    mins:0,
    secs:0
};

componentDidMount(){
    this.updateTimer()
}
updateTimer=()=>{

    const x = setInterval(()=>{
        let { eventDate} = this.state;

        if(eventDate <=0){
            clearInterval(x)
        }else {
            eventDate = eventDate.subtract(1,"s");
            const hours = eventDate.hours();
            const mins = eventDate.minutes();
            const secs = eventDate.seconds();

            this.setState({
                hours,
                mins,
                secs,
                eventDate
        })}},1000)

};
render() {
    const {hours, mins, secs} = this.state;

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {`${("0" + hours).slice(-2)}`}
                    <BlinkingText interval={1000}>:</BlinkingText>
                {`${("0" + mins).slice(-2)}`}
                    <BlinkingText interval={1000}>:</BlinkingText>
                {`${("0" + secs).slice(-2)}`}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```